# NodeJS calling prototype from another

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, node-modules, prototypal-inheritance

I keep getting `X` is not a function when trying to use another method on the same object. Test code below:

OBJECT1 :

```
"use strict"

let Mod1OBJ = function () {}

Mod1OBJ.prototype.first = function first () {
  console.log('first')
}

exports.Mod1OBJ = new Mod1OBJ()
```

OBJECT2 :

```
"use strict"

const { Mod1OBJ } = require(`./mod1.js`)

let Mod2OBJ = function () {}

Mod2OBJ.prototype.second = function second () {
  Mod2OBJ.deferred()
  console.log('second')
}

Mod2OBJ.prototype.deferred = function deferred () {
  Mod1OBJ.first()
  console.log('deferred')
}

exports.Mod2OBJ = new Mod2OBJ()
```

Index.js:

```
"use strict"

const { Mod2OBJ } = require(`./lib/pack1/mod2.js`)
Mod2OBJ.deferred()
Mod2OBJ.second()
```

On execution:

```
first
deferred
/path to file/mod2.js:8
Mod2OBJ.deferred()
          ^
TypeError: Mod2OBJ.deferred is not a function
```

Clearly 'deferred' is a function on `Mod2OBJ` but not when called within another method on the same object.

I thought I understood how to use modules/require/prototyping but clearly, I don't - I'm pulling my hair out trying to work out what I'm doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an instance of an object all properties of prototype copy then after to that object. If you want to access before creating an instance of the object you can use `prototype` or `this`.

**Try this:**

```
Mod2OBJ.prototype.second = function second () {
  Mod2OBJ.prototype.deferred()
  console.log('second')
}
```

**EDITED =======**
**Second way:**

```
Mod2OBJ.prototype.second = function second () {
  this.deferred()
  console.log('second')
}
```

Comment: Good idea but i'm now getting this:                                  Mod2OBJ.protoype.deferred()
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'deferred' of undefined

Comment: Because you did spell mistake `protoype`. You should use `prototype`

Comment: DOH! - Okay yea that worked. Thanks.  I'm still not entirely sure why I need to refer to the prototype at that point but I'm not going to argue with it - it works.

Comment: Because, When you create the instance of Mod2OBJ properties from the prototype are copied to the object. till now prototype function would not be available. If you want to access the methods of the instance from within its another method you could use `this`. Edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; I had already tried the 'this' experiment and got it to work however in the 'real world' usage the external calling code could be from an eventEmitter so 'this' won't be the object itself.

Comment: But that is just something I need to manage (or refactor my code) either way I can move forward now - thank you.

Comment: No need to refactor. You can simply use `this` or `prototype`. It is just all about the requirement. If you want to use any prototypal method before creating an instance of an object, that is totally fine.